# Converting truecolor RGB image to indexed colors

Tags: image-processing, rgb, color-palette

I want to convert a 24bit RGB image (8 bit for each channel) 8 bit using an indexed color palette.

My initial idea was to create an array and simply count the amount of times each color was represented in the image, but I figured it would be wasteful if there were large areas with slight change in color that used up all of the palette space in favor of smaller, but maybe more significant color groups.

Once I complete building the palette, my idea was to consider each RGB color as a 3-dimensional matrix and compare its dot product with each entry in the palette.

...

As you might see, I'm not completely in on the terminology, but I hope you get what I mean :)

My question is; Is anyone able to share insights on how to approach this or perhaps put me in the right direction to any reading material online?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [color quantization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_%28image_processing%29).

Answer (score 5):

According to [Paul Heckbert's paper from 1982](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.46.3830&rep=rep1&type=pdf) popularity algorithm is inferior to Median Cut.

There's family of Median-Cut like (space subdivision) algorithms that choose different criteria, e.g. [minimize variance](http://www.ece.mcmaster.ca/~xwu/cq.c) of colors in each partition).

There's fast, but ugly subdivision using Octtree.

There are clustering algorithms such as K-Means and [Linde-Buzo-Gray](http://www.data-compression.com/vq.html).

An interesting odd one is [NeuQuant](http://members.ozemail.com.au/~dekker/NEUQUANT.HTML) neural network.

---

I'm still trying to figure out the best one for [pngquant](http://pngquant.org/).