# How to convert an RGB image to indexed format?

Tags: c++, image, imagemagick, color-palette

So I have an array of pixels (RGB8 format) that I need to convert to an indexed format. I have already calculated the color palette that I want to use:

```
RGBColor rgbPalette[256];
for (int i = 1; i <= 85; i++)
{
    rgbPalette[i].R = ((86 - i) * 255) / 85;
    rgbPalette[i + 85].G = ((86 - i) * 255) / 85;
    rgbPalette[i + 170].B = ((86 - i) * 255) / 85;
}
```

Now I'm just stumped on how to take the pixels from my image and calculate the distance of the each of those pixels from my color palette.

The image library I'm using is ImageMagick. I know they provide quantize functions, but I need to "force" this palette on an image, and AFAIK ImageMagick doesn't provide any functions to achieve this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5221708/3425536) might be helpful.

Comment: So the the user who posted that question has a different problem than mine. From what I'm understanding, he just wants a way to convert an RGB image to an indexed image, but also dynamically produce a color palette that results in the image not losing much quality (and the answers point him to quantize algorithms like NeuQuant). My problem is a little different: I already have a color palette that I want to use, and it will restrict the image to only shades of red, blue, and green. So I just need to figure out how to calculate the distance of each pixel from the generated color palette.

Comment: If you already have the color palette you could use the map() method of Magick++ (http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#remap) or am I misunderstanding what you are asking?

Comment: But that takes a Magick::Image as a parameter? Would I have to convert my color palette to an image? Just seems like added overheard. I should probably note that I don't need the Magick::Image anymore after I calculate the indexed information, because I will be serializing the palette and indices to a file anyway. Which is why calculating the indices "by hand" won't be an issue. I just need to know how to calculate that.